# Can't set Android SDK Home path

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

Using Windows 8.1 and have installed the Stand Alone Android SDK for use with Phonegap and Cordova. The root path for the Android SDK is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. It seems no matter what I do (Environment Settings in Control Panel or command prompt string), I keep getting the ANDROID_HOME not set error when attempting to build.

Can somebody tell me the correct procedure for this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both `\android-sdk\tools` and `\android-sdk\platform-tools` to your path. If this has already been done can you please provide more information regarding the exact error that you are receiving and the steps that you have followed to get to the stage that you are at?